# Регулярное выражение фильтрации лишних символов

Tags: qt, qregularexpression

Дано: строка содержащая ссылки, спец символы, смайлик и пр.
Задача: написать регулярное выражение которое будет игнорить все ненужное (ссылки, спец символы, смайлик и пр.) и оставлять лишь текст.

Я не силен в этом вопросе, может кто сталкивался с поддобным?

Comment: Приведите примеры текстов и что в них найти в соответствии с описанием метки [tag:регулярные-выражения]

Comment: @dIm0n к примеру `Как победить СИЛЬНОГО если ты ДРЫЩ   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_TIZBjOPdQ `

Comment: ссылки :`https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)`

Comment: язык программирования назови ;)

Comment: `спец символы`, какие???

Comment: И что надо найти? Должно быть чёткое условие. Прочитайте описание метки. И сформулируйте нормально вопрос. Вам интересно, кто сталкивался или как решить?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor язык `c#` символы `!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]:";'<>?,/`~\|`

Comment: @dIm0n мне нужно удалить ссылки, символы, смайлики, оставить лишь текст

Comment: на другом форуме мне рекоммендовали использывать отрицательный класс символов, мол оставит нужное а ненужное удалит, но я не в курске что это

Comment: может символы проще удалить без регулярок, а на pure c#

Comment: @VictorVosMottor как быть со смайлами,?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023682/how-do-i-remove-emoji-characters-from-a-string